# Comparing data in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I need to generate the daily percentage sales for each of the 700 products based on their daily sales for the last 9 years.
Here is an example of what my node script should generate:

```js
Shoes1 | +5% | -1% | +10% | +5% | -1% | +10% |... (and so one for 3000 days)
...
Shoes200 | +5% | -1% | +10% | +5% | -1% | +10% |... (and so one for 3000 days)
```

I have 2 structures in mind, but I'm not sure which one would work better since I have around 3000 days of daily sales for about 700 product to record.

Here is the first one.

```js
Product

    {
        product_title: name1;
        sales:[{sales_number1:date}]
       /* sales: [{45:010104}, {23:050214},..., {243:050614},.....]*/
    }

Here is the second one

Date

    {
        Day: 050114;
        sales:[{product name: sales_number1}]
        /* sales: [{shoes1: 45}, {shoes2:5},..., {shoes1000:14}]*/
    }
```

Any advice would very welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: The numbers 3000 and 700 are both not good choices for arrays, even with relatively small data sizes. You also seem to be looking for an up/down comparison of one day to the next, as well as comparisons against daily totals. Both of those last issues are not simple to solve. The whole issue lends to several stages of aggregation and combination of different sources. Stick with discrete records of product, sales, date fields as a starting point. But there are the combination issues to consider working to the final output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by your output that you want(showing percentage change for a particular shoe in comparison to previous day),the first approach would be better

```
Product

    {
        product_title: name1;
        sales:[{sales_number1:date}]
       /* sales: [{45:010104}, {23:050214},..., {243:050614},.....]*/
    }
```

because in that case you would be querying over the array of the same document and then calculating the percentages.If you go by the second approach then you would need to pick an element corresponding to different shoes from different documents' arrays and then calculate percentage that would create more complex query.